# How to place a third party script tag in the HEAD in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Gatsby sort of provides a way to manipulate the main html.js [link to gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/)

but this is still a React component and I need to place a custom analytics script inside the Head. I tried eval, surrounding the script content in curly bracket, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Since it will strip our script tags I just placed a script tag in the Head and set the attr dangerouslySetInnerHTML to the content of the script provided by third party. e.g. in the render function of html.js:

```
 const googleOptimizeFlickeringScript = {
  __html: `(function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){..........`
}
return (
  <html>
    <head>
      <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={googleOptimizeFlickeringStyle} />
      <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={googleOptimizeFlickeringScript}/>
```